# How can I check if the value in a JQuery input form is an URL and not a normal string?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui, validation

I am working on a C#.NET web application that use **JQuery mobile** for its view.

in a view I have a form that contains the following input field in which the user can put an URL:

```
<label for="nome">URL*:</label>
<input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="oval.url" id="url" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"  required="required"  value="@Model.oval.URL" />
```

My problem is that, using the previous code snippet, the user can insert any string but I want that it is considered as a valid value only a real URL (something like **www.thisisanurl.com** and not something **this is not an url**)

Can I do this check using JQuery? Or what can I do to solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: For what it's worth, `www.thisisanurl.com` is not an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this validation:

```
var urlregex =new RegExp("^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
if (urlregex.test(textval)){
    ...
}
```

[This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is jquery mobile I'll assume it is being viewed on a mobile device. Most mobile browsers support HTML5 input types. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.url.html

`<input type="url" ... />`